# Google Fonts in Firefox renders pixelated

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts, google-font-api

I am using Google Fonts service and I noticed that some fonts are rendered in a different way in Chrome and Firefox.

[See this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbLqz.png), using *Kite One* font.

Why does Firefox pixelate the text? What can I do via CSS or server-side to avoid this pixelation?

EDIT: I am including the font using Google Fonts api:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kite+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: Please include some code? how are you calling/adding your fonts?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this trick : `text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.004);`

The rendering of the police is part of the browser not really customisable by css.

Comment: I do not see any difference in the text by using your text-shadow trick in Firefox